# IPv6 structure definition error

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

```
 common.c:150:17: error: ‘const struct sockaddr_in6’ has no member named ‘sa_family’
```

This is the error I get when solving resolution of my incoming IPv6 from client.
Please advice

Comment: What is unclear about the message ? You're trying to access a member `sa_family` and the struct has no such member.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it named `sin6_family` and must be `AF_INET6`?

Read [more](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html)

Also please specify the target OS..

Answer (score 0):

From [Linux Manual Page IPV6](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html) :

```
       struct sockaddr_in6 {
           sa_family_t     sin6_family;   /* AF_INET6 */
           in_port_t       sin6_port;     /* port number */
           uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo; /* IPv6 flow information */
           struct in6_addr sin6_addr;     /* IPv6 address */
           uint32_t        sin6_scope_id; /* Scope ID (new in 2.4) */
       };
```

`sa_family` member does not exist, you should replace it by `sin6_family`